# Face Text Property: void, nil, default

Tags: faces, string, text-properties

A string may hold a nil or `default` face text property, or its face text property is simply unspecified.
E.g.,

```lisp
#("void nil default"
  0 4   ; unspecified
  ()            
  5 8   ; nil face (this is an anonymous face, see the manual)
  (face ())
  9 16  ; default face
  (face default))
```

Although they are **usually** rendered to look the same, I wonder whether there is an exception?

Comment: They are not `eq` but they are `string=`? The first does not specify any properties, but the other two do?  Not sure what you are looking for.

Comment: *What are you asking?* Are you asking what face attributes a face should have so that it appears to have no effect, i.e., text with that face appears like text with face `default`? And only as shown by function `message`? What are you *really* trying to do? At *best*, this sounds like an [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/231821). You should be able to pare it down to something you really want/need to know.

Comment: You don't define what you mean by **"act like"**. Clearly, the 3 (1-char) strings you show at the outset are *different* (`"s"`, `#("s" 0 1 (face nil))`,  `#("s" 0 1 (face default))`), so clearly they don't **"act"** the same in all contexts. So far, the question seems completely undefined, to me.

Comment: To me it's unclear, as I said. To others it might be clear. You want to make two (or three) strings **"act"** the same, but you don't say what acting the same means for you. To me, this looks like an X-Y question: you don't say what you're trying to do or to understand; you instead try to ask about what you think might *solve* your real question/problem. But the something you try to ask is itself unclear: "Act like" isn't defined. Say what you **want to do** with the string: in what way you want the different strings to be/act the same.

Comment: You struggle with whether `nil` or face `default` is better. Better for what? Better in what way? You don't say what you want, so it's hard/impossible to help you choose which choice is "better" (for you, in some way).

Comment: @Drew: I want to know what value can be assigned to `my/face` so that the *message* emitted by `(minibuffer-message (propertize "s" 'face my/face))` will have the same appearance as the *message* emitted by `(minibuffer-message "s")`. It seems that the *message*s emitted by `(minibuffer-message "s")` & `(minibuffer-message #("s" (face nil)))` & `(minibuffer-message #("s" (face default)))` have the same appearances (ie, same foreground, same font, same weight, etc) -- I'm not sure if it's *always* true: maybe `nil` always works, or `default`, or some other value. |||| Thanks for your patience.

Comment: _Yes, they have the same appearance in the echo area_, as you can no doubt see, yourself. I asked in my first comment if that's what your question is. Since you can see that yourself, the question appears unclear - why ask if that's what the appearance is if that's what you can see? (I'm still guessing X-Y.)

Comment: @Drew: If you ask "*Are you asking what face attributes a face should have so that it appears to have no effect, i.e., text with that face appears like text with* no face property?" Yes! |||| "*why ask if that's what the appearance is if that's what you can see?*" --- Because I don't know whether it's *guaranteed*. IOW, when a string is displayed in the *echo area*, does a `nil` face property means inheriting all the attributes of `default`? what about no face property? |||| Thanks again for your patience!

Comment: `nil` is the same as having no `face` property.

Comment: Using a face that has exactly the same behavior as face `default` (e.g. only inherits from it) is the same as using face `default`, which is also the same as frame parameter `default`, and which is the default behavior.

Comment: @Drew: So when a no-property string is displayed by `minibuffer-message`, Emacs uses the `default` face for it, right? If so, then you've answered my question.

Comment: Yes. Displaying with face `default` is the same as displaying with no `face` text/overlay property - face `default` has the same foreground, background, and font as the frame (see frame parameters and `default-frame-alist`). See (emacs) `Face Customization`.

Comment: @Drew: Thank you. In this context, both `nil` and `default` are good choices for `my/face`. I'll accept it if you post an answer.

Answer (score 0):

###### nil and `default` always look the same.

[`(info "(emacs) Face Customization")`](https://gnu.org/s/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Face-Customization.html):

> A face does not have to specify every single attribute; ... .
> Any unspecified attribute is taken from the special face named `default`, whose attributes are all specified.

Since nil face (i.e., an anonymous face which is `()`) doesn't specify any attribute, all its attributes will fall back to `default`.

###### Void face sometimes looks different.

[`(info "(elisp) Displaying Faces")`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Displaying-Faces.html):

> Here is the order in which Emacs merges the faces, from highest to lowest priority:
>
> - ...
> - **If the text contains a `face`** or `mouse-face` **property**, Emacs applies the specified faces and face attributes.
> - If the text lies within the mode line of the selected window, Emacs applies the `mode-line` face. ...
> - If the text comes from an overlay string via `before-string` or `after-string` properties, ...
> - If any given attribute has not been specified during the preceding steps, Emacs applies the attribute of the `default` face.